# Serve currently uploaded code from Arduino

Tags: esp8266, uploading, http

I'm creating a project where multiple ESP8266 12-E's are connected together. I want to use ArduinoOTA with the HTTP option (described [here](http://esp8266.github.io/Arduino/versions/2.0.0/doc/ota_updates/ota_updates.html)) and I want to have one ESP be able to send its code to another. I just need to figure out how to get the currently uploaded code in the form of cpp.bin in the Arduino language from the Arduino, without using an external computer, and then serve it (I can figure out the serving part though). How could I go about this?

Comment: see the ESP8266httpUpdate example

Comment: I've already seen that example, I just want to figure out a way to get the code uploaded to the ESP from the ESP. Thanks though!

Comment: I am not sure what the problem is? use SPIFFS to store the bin

Comment: OK, that's a good idea. I can't access the code without storing it though?

Comment: you want to clone the program of the esp to other esp?

Comment: Exactly, but I can't figure out how to get an ESP's own uploaded code